# How to pass parameter to a gen_server function?

Tags: parameters, erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

I have a `gen_server` which increments the counter each time it's `increment()` function is called.

```
-module(genserver).
-export([start_link/0, start/0, increment/0]).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

init([]) ->
    {ok, "counter.txt"}.

start() ->
    gen_server:start({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

increment() ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, increment).

handle_call(increment, _From, File) ->
    Counter = case file:read_file(File) of
        {ok, Binary} -> binary_to_integer(Binary);
        {error, enoent} -> 0
    end,
    ok = file:write_file(File, integer_to_binary(Counter + 1)).

handle_cast(_Req, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

Here is the shell execute example

```
Eshell V7.3  (abort with ^G)
1> c("C:/Users/guga.melkadze/Desktop/testgen"). 
{ok,testgen}
2> testgen:start().
{ok,<0.39.0>}
3> testgen:increment().
920
4> testgen:increment().
921
5> testgen:increment().
922
```

Now I need to send one parameter every time I call the `genserver:increment()` method. For example `genserver:increment(someParameter)`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `increment` function to send a tuple instead of just an atom:

```
increment(N) ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {increment, N}).
```

And update the `handle_call` clause to use it:

```
handle_call({increment, N}, _From, File) ->
    Counter = case file:read_file(File) of
        {ok, Binary} -> binary_to_integer(Binary);
        {error, enoent} -> 0
    end,
    ok = file:write_file(File, integer_to_binary(Counter + N)).
```

---

Note that your `handle_call` function doesn't return the type of value expected by the `gen_server` behaviour, so this process will likely crash after each request.  You should add something like this as the last line:

```
{reply, ok, File}.
```

Comment: You helped me a lot, Thanks!